# QCA QtCrypto in QT Problem

Tags: c++, qt

I had just imported a downloaded files (qca-2.0.1-mingw) through my project and successfully imported it into my project.

My Problem is now this:

How could i use the encryption and decryption function of QCA.

I had found this [link](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/ciphertest_8cpp-example.html) but whenever i added this code to my codes my project doesn't run at all.

Comment: "my project doesn't run at all" is not enough information for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against the QCA lib, did you do that? (I'm not sure what you mean by "imported the files").

If you follow the installation steps inside the README/INSTALL file which comes with QCA you should just be able to add this to your Qt project file to link against QCA:

```
CONFIG += crypto
```

Or you can still add the QCA lib yourself, but I would prefer to use the above approach because it's platform independent.

After that you should be able to build the examples and use all the classes of QCA.

---

Extract from the INSTALL file of QCA 2.0.3:

```
Installing QCA
--------------

QCA requires Qt 4.2 or greater.

For Unix/Linux/Mac:

  ./configure
  make
  make install
  /sbin/ldconfig, if necessary

For Windows:

  configure
  nmake (or make)
  installwin
```